# Function to append an array of classes, then split those classes in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

I have a table that is generated:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input /></td>
    <td><span>30</span></td>
    <td><input /><td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is the basic structure. There are actually many `<tr>` elements that all look virtually the same. For each tr, I need to append a class like `a1, b1, c1` on certain elements. So after this function it should look like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="a1" /></td>
    <td><span class="a2">30</span></td>
    <td><input class="a3" /><td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="b1" /></td>
    <td><span class="b2">30</span></td>
    <td><input class="b3" /><td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And on until the last group like this, each one a letter increase over the last group.

After that I'm going to need to do calculations to I will have to split these classes. Something like:

```
$("input").keyup(function(){
  var originalVal = $(this).attr("class");
  //Here I need to split this class to get just the letter (a) or (b) etc
  //Then I will perform the calculations like $(orignalVal + "1") * $(originalVal = "2") etc
```

I figure this will be the easiest way to do everything I want to do, which is calculate the a1 input times the a2 span and insert the result in the a3 input and so on for all the groups. I'm open to other suggestions as well.

Comment: What is the problem that you are having with the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: That's true, but the problem is that I have to reference these values later on in the process as well. Like `b3*z3` insert into `g3` etc.

Comment: I think it's unnecessary to add classes to the elements. It looks you can access every element via row and column index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split('');

$('table tr').each(function(i) {
    $('td', this).children().addClass(function(j) {
        return chars[i] + ++j;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4C4gN/

Comment: If OP has more than 26 `tr`s, I don't know how many "many" are, then this would be a simple improvement. http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/A4Fx8/

Comment: @Xotic750 Yes, or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/A4Fx8/2/).

Comment: Indeed, not sure which jQuery selector is the most efficient, though not relevant to the question. :)

Comment: @Xotic750 Obviously the above code is not efficient at all, it introduces at least 4 different _visible_ loops :) I would do it server-side.